# How to check PCI type and version of free PCI slot in Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, pci-express, pci

I know how to check how many PCI slots are not used yet on my server, by using `dmidecode` and looking for `Available` slots:

```
# dmidecode
[...]
Handle 0x0014, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI1
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Long
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        5.0 V is provided
        PME signal is supported
```

and I also know how to check what PCI type and version are all the slots in the server (available and used), by using `lspci -vvv` and looking for `LnkCap` data:

```
# lspci -vvv
[...]
00:1f.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    [...]
    LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ...
```

where the speed of 2.5GT/s and the 1x suggest it's a PCI-e 1x slot.
That's fine, but how do I relate these outputs to deduce what PCI type and version are the **free** slots in my server?

I initially tried to assume the `Handle` numbers of `dmidecode` matched the first column values in `lspci` output, but they don't. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

As per Mark Wagner's comment, the numbers between `lspci` and `dmidecode` do not match because `lspci` shows informations about a bridge, not a slot, and `lspci` doesn't show anything for unused slots. That means `lspci` is not useful in my case, my question is still the same, but likely the answer will not use `lspci`.

Comment: The output from `lspci` is information about a bridge, not a slot. `lspci` only shows information about slots with a card in them.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that explains why numbers do not match. Given that, I assume `lspci` is almost useless in my case. Any clues about how to get the information I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dmidecode with slot option something like this:

$ sudo dmidecode -t slot  |grep -A 4 -B 5 Available

Handle 0x0900, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
Designation: PCI1
Type: x8 PCI Express 3 x16
Current Usage: Available
Length: Long
ID: 1
Characteristics:
3.3 V is provided

if you want to chech which one are in use is the same thing:

$ sudo dmidecode -t slot  |grep -A 4 -B 5 "In Use"

Handle 0x0901, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
Designation: PCI2
Type: x16 PCI Express 3
Current Usage: In Use
Length: Long
ID: 2
Characteristics:
3.3 V is provided